# If number patter for x times

Tags: python

The situation is that I have a sensor that gives of numbers from the distance on 0cm to 700cm every 2 seconds.

Is it possible to execute a code that reads the last five printed numbers and if they are all above 400cm for it to print something?

Comment: Almost without question, it is possible.  What is it?  We haven't got the faintest idea how you're even reading the sensor.

Comment: How do you read output from sensor? Is there any way how to detect, that new number appears or just try to read number every two seconds (or shorter interval should be better)?

Comment: When you read a number from the sensor and print it, do you also save it somewhere?  Like in a text file, or a python list?

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_sensor(data={}):
    value = get_next_value()
    data["sum"] = (data.get("sum",0)+(value>400))*(value>400)
    return data["sum"]

list(iter(read_sensor,5))
print "OK I got 5 values all over 400"
```

is one possible way ... I guess ... your co workers might hate you ...

Comment: Python fail no one, do not initiate mutable objects in kwargs ;) Or are you actaully using it as a feature here.

Comment: of coarse im using it as a feature ... (as I said his co-workers will hate him)